# Is my private key exposed while signing some data with metamask?

Tags: signature, private-key

My friend's metamask account was hacked and earlier he signed a message on a malicious site, so I wanted to know if there's any way how someone can get your private key this way. And if there's a way to do it, then I would like to know how ? (only for educational purpose)

Answer (score 1):

Signing message does not reveal the private key, only proves the fact that message was signed by the owner the address derived from that key.

A bit more on the topic could be found here https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/06transactions.asciidoc

Comment: [link](https://consensys.net/blog/developers/protecting-your-ethereum-private-key-with-ethsigner/) this blog by consensys says that private key can be compromised in dapps, depending about how they are built.

Comment: Dapp architecture shouldn't be an issue here, private key is stored with metamask, as long as it won't leak it through some kind of vulnerability signature itself won't reveal it